# iPhone:Recording conversation feature?

Tags: iphone

I want to develop an iPhone application which has to record the phone conversation. Can some one give me the instruction how can i achieve this?

thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is currently not possible.  The iPhone doesn't allow applications to run in the background.  When the phone application comes to the front (i.e. you get/make a phonecall), all other applications are shut down.

Answer (score 2):

This is currently not possible with the SDK. Not sure outside of it.

Answer (score 1):

Since background applications aren't possible and calls cause a foreground application to relinquish control, there's no way this could be done.

Answer (score 1):

You can find something like that [here](http://www.recordertheapp.com/support/). Seems to use an external service and goes around the restrictions (no background apps) by that. Maybe that helps.